# Автоматическое обновление данных из БД на странице

Tags: java, веб-программирование

Реализую небольшой maven-проект с выводом данных из БД. Проект основан на MVC архитектуре и суть его такова: на главной странице (index.jsp) находится таблица с информацией о фильмах, кроме того здесь же присутствует возможность редактирования каждого из них, удаления и добавления нового. В качестве модели используются класс film и класс filmsDatabase, который получает данные из БД (использую PostgreSQL):

```
    public class Film {
    public int id;
    public String title;
    public String genre;
    public String director;
    public int year;
    public int rating;

    public Film(String title, String genre, String director, int year, int rating) {
        this.title = title;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.director = director;
        this.year = year;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
}


public class FilmsDatabase {
    private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test";
    private static final String USER = "postgres";
    private static final String PASS = "*";

    private static Connection getDBConnection() {
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        //System.out.println("PostgreSQL JDBC Driver successfully connected");

        try {
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            //System.out.println("You successfully connected to database now");
        }

        return dbConnection;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Film> select() throws SQLException{
        ArrayList<Film> films = new ArrayList<>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM films ORDER BY id";

        try (Connection dbConnection = getDBConnection(); Statement stmt = dbConnection.createStatement()) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String title = rs.getString("title");
                String genre = rs.getString("genre");
                String director = rs.getString("director");
                int year = rs.getInt("year");
                int rating = rs.getInt("rating");
                Film film = new Film(title, genre, director, year, rating);
                films.add(film);
                film.setId(id);
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return films;
    }

    public static void insert(Film film) throws SQLException {
        String query = "INSERT INTO films(title, genre, director, year, rating) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        try (Connection dbConnection = getDBConnection(); PreparedStatement statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            statement.setString(1, film.getTitle());
            statement.setString(2, film.getGenre());
            statement.setString(3, film.getDirector());
            statement.setInt(4, film.getYear());
            statement.setInt(5, film.getRating());
            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static Film selectOne(int id) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE id = ?";
        Film film = null;

        try (Connection dbConnection = getDBConnection(); PreparedStatement stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            stmt.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()){
                String title = rs.getString("title");
                String genre = rs.getString("genre");
                String director = rs.getString("director");
                int year = rs.getInt("year");
                int rating = rs.getInt("rating");
                film = new Film(title, genre, director, year, rating);
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return film;
    }

    public static void update(Film film) {
        String query = "UPDATE films SET title = ?, genre = ?, director = ?, year = ?, rating = ? WHERE id = ?";

        try (Connection dbConnection = getDBConnection(); PreparedStatement stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            stmt.setString(1, film.getTitle());
            stmt.setString(2, film.getGenre());
            stmt.setString(3, film.getDirector());
            stmt.setInt(4, film.getYear());
            stmt.setInt(5, film.getRating());
            stmt.setInt(6, film.getId());
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void delete(int id) {
        String query = "DELETE FROM films WHERE id = ?";

        try(Connection dbConnection = getDBConnection(); PreparedStatement stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            stmt.setInt(1, id);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Для реализации контроллеров я использовал java servlet. Как пример, страница добавления нового фильма и соответствующий ей CreateServlet:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Добавление нового фильма</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Добавление нового фильма</h2>
<form method="post">
    <label>Название фильма</label><br>
    <input name="title"/><br><br>
    <label>Жанр фильма</label><br>
    <input name="genre"/><br><br>
    <label>Режиссер фильма</label><br>
    <input name="director"/><br><br>
    <label>Год выхода фильма</label><br>
    <input name="year" type="number"/><br><br>
    <label>Рейтинг фильма</label><br>
    <input name="rating" type="number"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Сохранить"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CreateServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/create.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
            String title = request.getParameter("title");
            String genre = request.getParameter("genre");
            String director = request.getParameter("director");
            int year = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("year"));
            int rating = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rating"));
            Film film = new Film(title, genre, director, year, rating);
            FilmsDatabase.insert(film);
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/index");
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/create.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь же возникла необходимость реализовать автоматическое обновление главной страницы при любом обновлении информации в БД. Т.е. например если открыть две одинаковые вкладки в браузере и в одной изменить информацию - вторая должна автоматически обновиться (ну или хотя бы вывести предупреждение, что мол "информация обновилась, не хотите ли вы обновить страницу?"). И тут возник вопрос как это реализовать. Пытался гуглить в интернете, находил множество примеров с онлайн-чатами, но так и не смог понять алгоритм, по которому мне это нужно сделать. Пока что пришел лишь к выводу, что скорее всего нужно использовать websocket. Попробовал реализовать ServerEndpoint класс, но дальше дело не продвинулось...

```
import javax.websocket.*;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

@ServerEndpoint("/ws")
public class PushUpdates {
    private static final Set<Session> SESSIONS = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        SESSIONS.add(session);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        SESSIONS.remove(session);
    }

    public static void sendAll(Film film) {
        synchronized (SESSIONS) {
            for (Session session : SESSIONS) {
                if (session.isOpen()) {
                    session.getAsyncRemote().sendObject(film);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Не могли ли вы мне подсказать как это можно реализовать?

Comment: вижу что-то для бека, но ведь и на клиенте и на JavaScript  нужно написать код - реализовать подключение ... попробуйте посмотреть на socket.io https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

Answer (score 0):

каждая страница должна иметь подключение к северу по ws, и передавая информацию на сервер с одной страницы нужно отправить на другую(другие) которые "подписаны" на такие события.